# WPF ListView items duplicated

Tags: c#, wpf, listview

I am having a unique trouble with my program. Let me explain the scenario.

I have a ListView that is bound to a ObservableCollection which is initially empty. The observable collection gets it data from an IAsync service.

After loading, the listview shows duplicate of the items. I used snoop to check the bindings and its confirmed that the items source that it is bound to has 2 items, but the listview has created 4 items. Also interestingly the duplicate entries are bound to the right item.

Can anyone shed some light on this matter ?

Comment: Can you supply the code?

Comment: Please show XAML and ViewModel/code behind

Answer (score 0):

Try turning off virtualization

[VirtualizingStackPanel.IsVirtualizing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.virtualizingstackpanel.isvirtualizing.aspx)

Or you may be able to virtualize but turn off recycling

[VirtualizationMode Enumeration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.virtualizationmode.aspx)